# Function to select a row whose kth element is closest to a given number

Tags: function-construction

I'm trying to write a function that picks out the row of a Matrix whose `kth` element is closest to some given number that will be given to me.

So for example,

```
list = Table[{i, FromCharacterCode[70 + i]}, {i, 1, 10}]
{{1, "G"}, {2, "H"}, {3, "I"}, {4, "J"}, {5, "K"}, {6, "L"}, {7,"M"}, {8, "N"}, {9, "O"}, {10, "P"}}
```

[image]

```
b = RandomReal[{0, 6}]
4.42427
```

So I want to pick the row whose 1st element is closest to 4.42427. The function should spit out

```
{4,"J"}
```

**Edit**

Btw, thanks to Mr. Wizard's help, my crappy code works!!

```
disT[l_List, bb_?NumericQ, cc_Integer] := Table[Abs[bb - l[[j, cc]]], {j, 1,Dimensions[l][[1]]}]

srcH[ll_List, bb_?NumericQ, cc_Integer] := Drop[First[Sort[Transpose[    Prepend[Transpose[ll], disT[ll, bb, cc]]], #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]],1]


disT[list,b,1]
{3.42427, 2.42427, 1.42427, 0.42427, 0.57573, 1.57573, 2.57573,3.57573, 4.57573,5.57573}

srcH[list, b, 1]
{4, "J"}
```

Now I will Implement Mr. Wizard's code or Daniel's code for my actual problem. Thanks!!

**Edit2**

To expand on what I wrote under Mr. Wizard's answer. The actual task that I am trying to accomplish involves many lists $list_k  \; k \; \in \{1,100\}$ and many comparison lists $b_k = (b_{k1},...,b_{kj}), \; \; k \; \in \{1,100\}$ .

So For example:

```
 list[57]=  {{1, "G"}, {2, "H"}, {3, "I"}, {4, "J"}, {5, "K"}, {6, "L"}, {7,"M"}, {8, "N"}, {9, "O"}, {10, "P"}}

 b[57]={0.1,7.3,9.8}

 list[79]=  {{2.8, "G"}, {3.4, "H"}, {4.5, "I"}, {5.1, "J"}, {6.05, "K"}, {7.1, "L"}, {8.3,"M"}, {8.5, "N"}, {9, "O"}, {10, "P"}}

 b[79]={5,7.2,8.1}
```

and my final output, as index goes from 1 to 100, will find rows where the first element is close to the elements of b[k] respectively:

```
 output[57]={{1,G},{7,M},{10,P}}
 output[79]={{5.1,J},{7.1,L},{8.3,M}}
```

I was planning on using the function I got from the help here at mma.se inside a table or something but since Mr. Wizard has mentioned speeding up computation, I figured it would be best if I described the exact problem I am working on.

Comment: How are you measuring distance from a real to a character?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I only want to use the Distance function on columns which have real entries.

Comment: You mean the row whose first element is closest, right?

Comment: @Rojo in this example, the first element but in my actual problem some kth element.

Comment: @Rojo and Daniel .. I just noticed and fixed the typo in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason I wanted this as a function is because I will wind up using
>   it on lots of different lists for lots of different columns. I'm guess
>   the function form is better for that.

If you are going to be using the function nearly at random, with little repetition of lists then you may do well with:

```
nff[num_?NumericQ, l_List] := Nearest[#[[1]] -> # & /@ list, b, 1][[1]]
```

If you will use the function for many columns within a single list I propose that you let `Nearest` built a function for you.  If memory is not a limitation (the lists are not too large) then I propose using memoization to streamline this process.

```
m : makeNF[list_List] := m = Nearest[#[[1]] -> # & /@ list]

nffmem[num_?NumericQ, l_List] := makeNF[l][num][[1]]
```

This pair of functions will build a `Nearest` function only once for each list, caching it as a definition of `makeNF`.  You could use `ClearAll[makeNF]` and then evaluate the code above to clear these cached values if memory starts to get low.

Comment: I just looked up memoization on wikipedia. It will take be a bit to appreciate and understand the differences between the two ways you described. To address your comment, I actually have a list of 20 different numbers each for about a 100 Matrices. So `b` , the comparison number, is itself a list and for each of those b's I want to find something in column k closest to it. Then I do this for a 100 Matrices, each with a unique b.  This is for one set of overall parameters. So I might wind up doing 2000 such uses of the function, many many times.

Comment: @Amatya I'll be in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica) for a few minutes if you want to discuss this.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nearest.html).

```
nf = Nearest[Map[Rule[#[[1]], #] &, list]];

nf[b][[1]]
```

> ```
> {4, "J"}
> ```

Comment: Geez man, format your code! ;-p

Comment: Oh man! good MMA code is so slick! Thanks a lot Daniel! What was I doing wrong in my `disT` function though?

Comment: Also, can you please make your code into a function. I would like to learn how to do that. Why does `nff[num_numba, l_list] := Nearest[Map[Rule[#[[1]], #] &, l]][num][[1]]` and `nuff[b, list]` produce garbage?

Comment: Shorter: `nf = Nearest[#[[1]] -> # & /@ list]`

Comment: @Amatya you're using incorrect patterns.  As written you're trying to match objects with heads `list` and `numba` which are not built-in heads in *Mathematica*.  Also, if you are going to write this as a function that is called as shown, rather than building a function `nf` as Daniel's answer does, you would to better to use a different syntax for `Nearest`.  Try this:  `nff[num_?NumericQ, l_List] := 
 Nearest[#[[1]] -> # & /@ list, b, 1][[1]]`

Comment: oh.. the stuff after the `_` has meaning... I thought that was just so the programmer can keep track of stuff. Let me try your function.. thanks a lot Mr. Wizard!

Comment: @Amatya see [this slide](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html) for a summary of pattern objects.  There are quite a few of them!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks. The reason I wanted this as a function is because I will wind up using it on lots of different lists for lots of different columns. I'm guess the function form is better for that.